# BASH: calculate number of days to account expiration

Tags: bash, date, accounts

Objective: Output from Linux username, passwordlastchanged, passwordexpires in human readable format.

I pulled user info from `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` for users with shell `/bin/bash`

```
join -1 1 -2 1 -t : /etc/passwd /etc/shadow |grep bin/bash|awk -F\: '{print $1";"$9";$14}'
where
$1 = username
$9 = number of days since last password change, calculated from 1/1_1970
$14 = number of days to password expiry date, calculated from 1/1_1970
```

I can get a similar number as $9 and $14 for the current date

```
expr $(date +%S) /86400
```

Question: 
How do I output the value of $9-$(date +%s)/86400 and $14-$(date +%s)/86400 in my current one liner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please be aware that field 8 in `/etc/shadow` does NOT contain "password expiry date" but according to `man shadow` (on linux):

> **account expiration date**
>
> The date of expiration of the account, expressed as the number of days since Jan 1, 1970.
>      Note that an account expiration differs from a password expiration. . . 
>      An empty field means that the account will never expire.

Do you want "password expiration" or "account expiration"?

With the `join` in your question, all "shadow" fields will be shifted by 6 for further evaluation. The `grep` command is unnecessary; `awk` can do that. Try this adaption of your one-liner:

```
join -1 1 -2 1 -t : /etc/passwd /etc/shadow | awk -F: -v"TD=$(date +%s)" 'BEGIN {TD = TD / 86400} $7 ~ /bash$/ {print $1, int($9-TD), $14?int($14-TD):"never"}' OFS=";"
user1;-1429;never
user2;-1429;never
```

Comment: Ah yes: I've used the account expiration date on field 8 instead of maximum days valid in field 5. That changes the task slightly.

Comment: I'm after the number of days until password expiration or like in your example: the word 'never' if that is the case.

Comment: There's no "password expiration" field in `shadow`. You'd need to calculate it from "date of last password change" plus "maximum password age". Why don't you adapt the proposal and report back?

Answer (score 3):

Use `echo` as follows:

```
 echo "$(($9-$(date +%s)/86400 ))"
```

`$((...))` is an arithmetic expansion.

The usage of `...` in `$((...))` will be interpreted as an arithmetic expression. For example, a hexadecimal string will be interpreted as a number and converted to decimal. The whole expression will then be replaced by the numeric value that the expression evaluates to.

`$((...))` should be quoted as to not be affected by the shell's word splitting and filename globbing.

or

```
echo "$9-$(date +%s)/86400" | bc
```

`bc` stands for basic calculator and it can handle mathematical operations.